# Flutter : Is it possible to create multiple elements in a expansion tile?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I use Flutter and I would like to create a [ExpansionTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) List with 2 elements in the same Tile.

For example :

> name :/.......White-Space....../ Snow.
>
> firstname :/.......White-Space....../ John.
>
> location :/.......White-Space....../ Winterfell.

But I don't know if it's possible.(after some search on internet and doc)

I've tried to work with Column, Row,.. in children's property but nothing is effective.

Someone have a solution ?

My Code :

```
class Entry{
 const Entry(this.title,[this.children = const <Entry>[]]);
 final String title;
 final List<Entry> children;
 }

 const List<Entry> data = <Entry> [
 Entry(
 '   Profile',
 <Entry>[
   Entry('Jhon'),
   Entry('Snow'),
   Entry('Winterfell'),
 ],
),
```

...

```
  class Collapsible extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => EntryItem(data[index]),
      itemCount: data.length,
    );
  }
}
class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget{
  const EntryItem(this.entry);

  final Entry entry;

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root){
    if(root.children.isEmpty) return ListTile(title: Text(root.title));
    return ExpansionTile(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
        initiallyExpanded: true,
        key: PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
        title: Center(child: Text(root.title),),
    children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList()
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Edited)*

Is this what you're looking for?

```
class Collapsible extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if(i >= data.length) return null;
        return ExpansionTile(
          title: Text('name: ${data[i].title}'),
          children: [
            Text('firstname: ${data[i].children[0].title}'),
            Text('firstname: ${data[i].children[1].title}'),
          ]
        );
      },
      itemCount: data.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes But I don't want to use Row in the title :/

Comment: any reason you don't want to use Row?

Comment: because I just want the Section's title (ex : Profile) in the title

Comment: I see, and the rest should go into the `children` property of the `ExpandedList`?